# MeteorJS iron-router "sub-templates" or re-render prevention or optional parameter

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to migrate a two year old meteor project with many deprecated packages to the current version. But I'm stuck with iron-router and this:

1. A route `/map` showing an interactive map with markers
2. When a user click on a marker an absolute positioned  `div` with full-width-height opens and show a detail page
3. The url should change to `/map/<markerId>` so the user can share url and use back button
4. The div holding the map should **not** be destroyed or rerendered because the user should not loose his "map-state" like zooming & scrolling when going back

I tried several approaches but didn't find a solution that solve point 3 and 4 simultaneously.
With the old router package it just worked with the two routes setting a different Session variable and rendering the same template.

Thanks in advance for ideas

Comment: I believe you should be able to yield the render to an element. So when you  nav to the route the `action:` of the route will call a `.render` yielding to w.e area you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `to` parameter for Iron Router's `render` function:

```
this.render('markerdetails', { to: 'yieldname' });
```

To use that you need to specify a yield in your template containing the map:

```
{{> yield "yieldname"}}
```

Further reading on the `to` parameter: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#rendering-templates-into-regions-with-javascript

Not 100% sure what happens if a user just opens the URL. You could probably check if the map is already visibile and if not render the map first and then the marker into the yield.

Answer (score 0):

You could try switching from Iron Router to Meteorhacks' [Flow-Router](https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router/) because it has a better separation between routing and rendering, and rendering is not reactive. In fact Flow-Router doesn't handle its own rendering at all. Instead you can use MeteorHacks' [Flow-Layout](https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-layout) or something else if you'd like. Here's [Arunoda's article](https://meteorhacks.com/flow-router-and-subscription-management.html).

And here's a very basic example of Flow Router and Layout together.
It tries to render the least amount possible, or if you'd like, you can see how you could just change routes but do no rendering at all...

```
FlowRouter.route('/tasks', {
  subscriptions: function(){
    this.register('myTasks', Meteor.subscribe('tasks'))
  },
  action: function() {
    FlowLayout.render('layout1', { // the "layout" holds templates
      top: "header",
      main: "tasks" 
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Flow-Router seems to have a great conecpt like most of Arunodas stuff. But I suspect compatibility issues with other community packages. So I wanted to wait until these issues are solved before digging deeper in Arunodas Flow-World.